# Getting date into a label every time the date is changed

Tags: asp.net, jquery, vb.net

I am using this datetimepicker by Trent Richardson, I can get the date time picker to work, however after the date is changed i need it to be put into a hidden asp.net control that is in an update panel.

So how can i make it so everytime the user changes the date and time it is sent to a label.

http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So since it seems like it's just a extension of the jQuery ui datepicker, you could use the altField option: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#alt-field

or the onSelect Event to do it yourself: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-onSelect

Comment: if i want to use the regular jquery datetimepicker, which js files do i have to link to.